# $\sum x_n$ is divergent , $ \lim x_n=0$ and the partial sums of $\sum x_n$ are bounded

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does there exist a divergent series $\sum x_n$ such that $ \lim x_n=0$ and the partial sums of 
$\sum x_n$ are bounded ?

Comment: $1-1/2-1/2+1/3+1/3+1/3-1/4-1/4-1/4-1/4+\cdots$.

Comment: @DavidMitra well that is not divergent.. The Op probably meant non convergent though

Comment: @Ant It is indeed divergent.

Comment: @DavidMitra oh I'm sorry then. But you could explain why? It seems to me that is alternating between 0 and 1..

Comment: @Ant From Wikipedia: "In mathematics, a divergent series is an infinite series that is not convergent, meaning that the infinite sequence of the partial sums of the series does not have a finite limit."

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Ah okay then.. I have been taught that the term "divergent" means that goes to infinity, "non convergent" means does not have a limit. There is not a clear distinction though, that's why I misunderstood :)